# div extending beyond parent div when margin added

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble stopping my divs extending beyond the parent div when I add a margin. In the example below I've made the divs width 100%, then added margin-left: 32px; to the second div.

I want it to stay within the 100% width, but the margin-left seems to push it outside the parent div.

```css
.parent {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 540px;
    padding-right: 32px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    float: none;
}

.child-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.child-2 {
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;

}
#parent-box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent-box">
  <div class="child-1"><p>test</p></div>
  <div class="child-2"><p>test box</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So just remove the `width: 100%;` then …

Comment: 100% + something == overflow

Comment: easy also is to subtract the margin in child2, like '''width: calc(100% - 32px)'''

Comment: del width: 100%; from .child-2 class